# How you build GraphQL queries using (where:)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, prisma, prisma-graphql

I everyone,

I hope you are all safe, healthy, and happy in these scary times.  I am working on an e-commerce website based on Next.js Prisma, Yoga, and GraphQL.

I am having trouble building a query to see if a Type field is true on an item in my DB and only show those sandwiches on the homepage.

On the frontend, I have tried:

```
const FEATURED_SANDWICH_QUERY = gql`
  query FEATURED_SANDWICH_QUERY {
    sandwiches(orderBy: featured_DESC) {
      id
      image
      title
      description
    }
  }
`;
```

and `sandwiches(where: {featured_contains: true})` and `sandwiches(where: {featured: true})`

So far I am getting nothing returned or others errors

Here are the links to the backend query, data model, and schema.  I am new at this, what am I doing wrong building the query? Thanks For your help

[Query.js](https://github.com/WebRuin/lunchbox-full-stack/blob/Features/backend/src/resolvers/Query.js)

[datamodel.graphql](https://github.com/WebRuin/lunchbox-full-stack/blob/Features/backend/datamodel.graphql)

[schema.graphql](https://github.com/WebRuin/lunchbox-full-stack/blob/Features/backend/src/schema.graphql)

[Homepage.js](https://github.com/WebRuin/lunchbox-full-stack/blob/Features/frontend/components/Homepage.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sandwiches(where: {featured: true})` should work as per your schema.
Could you check again?

Comment: I left out an outer render() :|